# Symfony call get by Name from variable

Tags: symfony, getter

I would like to call a getter with the stored fieldname from the database.

For example, there are some fieldnames store like ['id','email','name'].

```
$array=Array('id','email','name');
```

Normally, I will call ->getId() or ->getEmail()....

In this case, I have no chance to handle things like this. Is there any possibility to get the variable as part of the get Command like...

```
foreach ($array as $item){
   $value[]=$repository->get$item();
}
```

Can I use the magic Method in someway? this is a bit confusing....

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do it like this :

```
// For example, to get getId()
$reflectionMethod = new ReflectionMethod('AppBundle\Entity\YourEntity','get'.$soft[0]);
$i[] = $reflectionMethod->invoke($yourObject);
```

With `$yourObject` being the object of which you want to get the id from.

EDIT : Don't forget the use to add :

```
use ReflectionMethod;
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Oh this is quite nice! Do I need to add any use statements? For the reason, symfony says "Attempted to load class "ReflectionMethod" from namespace "DatacareBundle\Controller".
Did you forget a "use" statement for another namespace? "

Comment: ok I found it. there was a missing \ : $reflectionMethod = new \ReflectionMethod(...//

Answer (score 8):

Symfony offers a special `PropertyAccessor` you could use:

```
use Symfony\Component\PropertyAccess\PropertyAccess;

$accessor = PropertyAccess::createPropertyAccessor();

class Person
{
    private $firstName = 'Wouter';

    public function getFirstName()
    {
        return $this->firstName;
    }
}

$person = new Person();

var_dump($accessor->getValue($person, 'first_name')); // 'Wouter'
```

http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/property_access/introduction.html#using-getters

Comment: Sorry Guys, but is there also a possibility to use this for setters?  
$new= new Whatever();
And then use a setter for all data which will come in?

Comment: @TheTom Check the linked doc. It's documented how to write to objects.

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php
// You can get Getter method like this
use Doctrine\Common\Inflector\Inflector;

$array = ['id', 'email', 'name'];
$value = [];

foreach ($array as $item){
    $method = Inflector::classify('get_'.$item);
    // Call it
    if (method_exists($repository, $method))
        $value[] = $repository->$method();
}
```