# Access WPF object by string variable

Tags: c#, wpf

I have x `ListViews` in my xaml Form:

- name: `lvExt1`
- name: `lvExt2`
- etc...

In my program I can access them directly with `lvExt1.Items` or similar.

I would like to access those within a function that has the number as parameter

Something like:

```
privat void accessListView(string number){

   return lvlExt"number".Items;
}
```

In Symfony (PHP) I can do it like this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/31142123/1092632

I do realize it may be something completely different, but only to express what I am trying to do.

Comment: [Try reading this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20857773/create-dynamic-variable-name)

Comment: May be `return (this.FindName("lvlExt" + number) as ListView).Items`

Comment: or LogicalTreeHelper.FindLogicalNode(this, "lvlExt" + number)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two ways:

1. Use the way that WPF provided:

   var lvlExt = this.FindName("lvlExt" + number) as ListView;

   var lvlExt = LogicalTreeHelper.FindLogicalNode(this, "lvlExt" + number);
2. Use an array to reference:

   var lvlExts = new ListView[3];

   ...

   var lvlExt =ListView[number];